# The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked when using auth.currentUser

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm new to flutter... I'm trying to get the state of the currently loggedIn user and notify the listeners using firebase but I'm getting this error `The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.` at the `auth.currentUser` but I don't understand why.

Below is my code.

```
_initialize() async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    bool loggedIn = prefs.getBool(LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
    if(!loggedIn){
      _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
    }else{
      await auth.currentUser().then((currentUser) async{
        _user = currentUser;
        _status = Status.Authenticated;
        _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(currentUser.uid);
      });

    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you're using an outdated tutorial with the latest libraries. `currentUser` is a property nowadays, and not a method. There is also no longer a need to `await` it, so:

```
if(!loggedIn){
  _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
}else{
  _user = auth.currentUser;
  _status = Status.Authenticated;
  _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(currentUser.uid);
}
```

Also see the FlutterFire documentation on [using authentication](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage) and [currentUser() is not working type why I am seeing the expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667623/currentuser-is-not-working-type-why-i-am-seeing-the-expression-doesnt-evaluat).