# Flutter firebase_dynamic_links : The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to integrate dynamic link in my flutter app using  `firebase_dynamic_links` package and I am not much familiar with dynamic links I am following a tutorial I try following code from tutorial. but on this line `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink` i got the error **The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.** I search a lot but didn't find any solution.

```
final PendingDynamicLinkData? data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    _handleDeepLinks(data);
   FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
     onSucess : (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLinkData) async {
       _handleDeepLinks(dynamicLinkData);
     },
     onError : (e) {
       print('This is error $e');
     }
   );
  }
```

it shows no error like this `FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink;`
Is there any change in  `firebase_dynamic_links` package?

Comment: can you refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66210916/15774176) is it helpful?

Comment: Divyani Yadav thats not too much helpful, i search alot if .onLink is changed but i didnt find anything related to this

Comment: are you following these docs ?- [1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/create) and [2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive).

Answer (score 0):

From the FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen() stream, it is recommended to set the result of your dynamic link to a variable or pass it to another widget and not return it directly as an argument to a function.

Here's a code that illustrates:

```
 Uri yourDynamicLink;

 FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen(
    (pendingDynamicLinkData) {
      if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
        yourDynamicLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link;
      }
    },
    onError : (e) {
     print('This is error $e');
   }
 );

// function to do something with your Uri goes here
```

Take a look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive#handle_deep_links) to see how it was used in Navigation