# currentUser: The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I need to update this code, not I'm not sure how. Does anyone have a clue?

```
_initialize() async{
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool loggedIn = prefs.getBool(LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
if(!loggedIn){
  _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
}else{
  await auth.currentUser().then((currentUser) async{
    _user = currentUser;
    _status = Status.Authenticated;
    _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(currentUser.uid);
  });

}
notifyListeners();
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked when using auth.currentUser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210328/the-expression-doesnt-evaluate-to-a-function-so-it-cant-be-invoked-when-using)

Answer (score 1):

"currentUser" is not a method anymore, it's a property.

```
_initialize() async{
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
bool loggedIn = prefs.getBool(LOGGED_IN) ?? false;
if(!loggedIn){
  _status = Status.Unauthenticated;
}else{

    _user = auth.currentUser;
    _status = Status.Authenticated;
    _userModel = await _userServices.getUserById(_user.uid);


}
notifyListeners();
}
```