# Error: "The expression is not evaluated as a function, so it cannot be invoked" when using Flutter Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I am facing a problem when using the Flutter Riverpod in a Flutter project. I get the following error: "The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked".

The error occurs in the following code snippet:

```
import 'package:amplify_auth_cognito/amplify_auth_cognito.dart';
import 'package:amplify_flutter/amplify_flutter.dart';
import 'package:fitmassdesktop/amplifyconfiguration.dart';
import 'package:fitmassdesktop/pages/home.dart';
import 'package:fitmassdesktop/pages/login.dart';
import 'package:fitmassdesktop/providers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  State<App> createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  bool _amplifyConfigured = false;

  @override
  void initState(){
  super.initState();
  _configureAmplify();
  }

  Future<void> _configureAmplify() async {
    await Amplify.addPlugins([
      AmplifyAuthCognito()
    ]);
    await Amplify.configure(amplifyconfig);
    setState(() {
      _amplifyConfigured = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: _amplifyConfigured ? 
      Consumer(
        builder: (context, watch, child) {
        final currentUser = watch(authUserProvider);
        return currentUser.when(
          data: (data){
          if(data == null){
            return const LoginPage();
          }
          return const HomePage();
        }, 
        loading: (){
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }, error: (e, st){
          return const LoginPage();
        }  
        );
      })
      : const HomePage()
    );
  }
  
}
```

The error occurs on the line where I use currentUser.when(...). As I understand it, the when is being invoked incorrectly or in an inappropriate context, resulting in this error.

Does anyone know what might be causing this error and how I can fix it properly?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what does your `authUserProvider` look like?

Comment: @Ruble this is the code for the authUserProvider:

`import 'package:fitmassdesktop/services/aws_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final authUserProvider = FutureProvider((ref){
  final authAWSRepo = ref.watch(authAWSRepositoryProvider);
  return authAWSRepo.user.then((value) => value);

});`

Comment: Welcome to the StackOverflow

Comment: Look into this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210328/the-expression-doesnt-evaluate-to-a-function-so-it-cant-be-invoked-when-using

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63667623/currentuser-is-not-working-type-why-i-am-seeing-the-expression-doesnt-evaluat